# trying to create main.java and second.java , not able to create

Tags: java, eclipse

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/diSoc.png)
main java file is created and not able to compile them will add scond.java in other page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQQUP.png)
second.java i tried to create , please help, please post screen shots if possible,
i created a two files in same pakage , one is main.java where the variable is present and one more is second.java where the method is pulling varible to the secon file , but as shown in image no able to compile the code , please let me know where am i doing wrong.

Comment: [Please never post images of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.

Comment: And please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: *How* did you get to this state? You haven't included steps to reproduce and answer where you went wrong.

Comment: I must be blind (or drunk): both images seems to be the same code; and both are neither `main.java` nor `second.java` - and the class named `scnd` is declared to be in `package scnd` but is not in the correct location, that is, not in folder named `scnd` (same name as the `package`) - it is actually listed (on left lower pane) as being in the `(deault package)`, aka no `package`

Comment: BTW be warned that Eclipse often has problems finding the `main` method in a non-public class, as in posted image (:-/), if such is really needed, that is, the class not being declared `public`, you must create the Run Configuration by *hand* (or mouse: menu Run -> Run Configurations...)

Comment: @user16320675, I believe _maina_ is _"main"_, and _scnd_ is _"second"_.

Comment: @user16320675 you are not drunk it is the same file!

Answer (score 0):

your scnd.java file are under the default package not under the scnd package so move it to the scnd package next to the maina.java file

or

remove the package scnd; statement from the scnd.java file

notice

the convention rule that you use camel case for your class which you did not

Answer (score 0):

> *"... i created a two files in same pakage ..."*

You're misunderstanding the *package*.  There is only 1 file in the *scnd* package.

Here is the *Java* tutorial on *packages*.
*[Creating and Using Packages (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Packages)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html)*.

To clarify, you have a project named *scnd*, a package named *scnd*, and also a file named *scnd.java*.

So, the file *scnd.java*, is within the *scnd* project, and not the *scnd* package.
As you can see in your screenshot, it says *"(default package)"* above *scnd.java*.

Your other file, *maina.java*, is correctly within the *scnd* package.

My suggestion would be to move the *scnd.java* file to the *scnd* package.
Or, you could try removing the *package scnd* declaration from the *scnd.java* file.